# LDAP server vs LDAP sdk

Tags: ldap, openldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I was reading through various open source ldap's.

1. OpenLDAP  - LDAP server
2. UnboundID - LDAP sdk

**Questions**

1. Can someone elaborate the difference between the **LDAP server** and **LDAP sdk** ?
2. It would more helpful if i get the answer for differences between OpenLDAP and UnboundID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. An LDAP server is a server. An SDK provides a client-side library.
2. OpenLDAP and UnboundID are two different LDAP products. OpenLDAP provides both a server and a client, and an SDK. UnboundID provides an SDK and possibly a server too, you would have to ask them.